# Why am I getting strong parameter errors in the Rails Console in rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, strong-parameters, awesomeprint

I want to call this in my console (`ap` is the awesome print gem):

```
ap Purchase.last(10)
```

but I get this error:

```
ActionController::UnfilteredParameters: unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash
```

It works like this:

```
irb(main):020:0> ap Purchase.last
#<Purchase:0x00007f86b792a320> {
                              :id => 28445,
                         :user_id => 10177,
                      :product_id => nil,
                    :product_type => nil,
                           :price => 9.0,
                    :gateway_code => nil,
                     :gateway_msg => nil,
                :gateway_response => nil,
                      :created_at => Fri, 18 May 2018 22:20:10 UTC +00:00,
                      :updated_at => Fri, 18 May 2018 22:20:10 UTC +00:00,
                  :checkout_total => 9.0,
                      :successful => true,
                         :cart_id => 17242,
                   :report_errors => nil,
    :transacted_value_of_products => 9.0,
            :comp_credits_applied => 0.0
}
```

And without `ap` like this:

```
irb(main):022:0> Purchase.last(10)
D, [2018-05-25T20:58:54.692575 #70552] DEBUG -- :   Purchase Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "purchases".* FROM "purchases" ORDER BY "purchases"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 10]]
+-------+---------+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id    | user_id | product_id | product_... | price | gateway_... | gateway_msg | gateway_... | created_at  | updated_at   | checkout... | successful | cart_id | report_e... | transact... | comp_cre... |
+-------+---------+------------+-------------+-------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+------------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 28436 | 10471   |            |             | 5.0   |             | Completed   | {"mc_gro... | 2018-05-... | 2018-05-1... | 5.0         | true       | 17228   | {}          | 5.0         | 0.0         |
| 28437 | 9754    |            |             | 1.99  |             | Completed   | {"mc_gro... | 2018-05-... | 2018-05-1... | 2.48        | true       | 15273   | {}          | 1.99        | 0.0         |
| 28438 | 10472   |            |             | 9.0   |             |             | {\n  "id... | 2018-05-... | 2018-05-1... | 9.0         | true       | 17231   | {}          | 9.0         | 0.0         |
| 28439 | 10348   |            |             | 9.0   |             |             |             | 2018-05-... | 2018-05-1... | 9.0         | true       | 17235   |             | 9.0         | 0.0         |
```

But not with an argument and `ap`

```
irb(main):021:0> ap Purchase.last(3)
ActionController::UnfilteredParameters: unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash
    from (irb):21
```

It turns out I can't do much of anything:

```
irb(main):023:0> ap Purchase.find(28444)
ActionController::UnfilteredParameters: unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash
    from (irb):23

irb(main):024:0> ap Purchase.find(28444).gateway_response
ActionController::UnfilteredParameters: unable to convert unpermitted parameters to hash
    from (irb):24
```

What's going on?

Comment: What is `gateway_response` in the database? Serialized `params` perhaps?

Comment: The reason I ask because `ActionController::Parameters` used to inherit from `Hash` so you could `serialize :stuff, Hash`, put `params` into `stuff`, and end up with end up with a blob of YAML in your database that is marked as an `ActionController::Parameters` instance. But `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from `Hash` and its `to_h` method raises an exception. The result is that changing Rails versions can leave your database littered with broken data if you haven't been very careful.

Comment: @muistooshort This is it. I not all of my purchases have a gateway response, since purchases can be made in different ways. Some gateway reponses come from Authorize.net (old ones) some from Stripe, and some from Paypal. Based on my code those serialized responses have different classes, and as you say it looks like the ones come from Paypal are serialized as ActionController::Parameters. I've recently upgraded my app from 4.2 to 5.2 and it looks like I need to clean my db. Feel free to post your comment as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## What's Happening and Why

`ActionController::Parameters` (which is what `params` works with in controllers) used to inherit from `HashWithIndifferentAccess` which inherits from `Hash`. So `ActionController::Parameters < Hash` used to be true as would something like:

```
params.require(:x).permit(some_hash: %i[key1 key2]).is_a? Hash
```

If you were digging a `Hash` out of `params`:

```
some_hash = params.require(:x).permit(some_hash: ...)
```

and serializing that in a model:

```
class M < ApplicationRecord # Or ActiveRecord::Base in the past
  serialize :h, Hash
end
#...
m.h = some_hash
```

you could end up with some YAML like this in your database:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
...
```

rather than the expected plain YAMLized hash.

But then Rails5 comes along and [`ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from `Hash`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#action-pack-notable-changes):

> - Make `ActionController::Parameters` no longer inherits from `HashWithIndifferentAccess`.

and calling `to_h` or `to_hash` on an `ActionController::Parameters` now raises an exception.

If you upgrade your code and try to load a model with serialized data in it:

```
serialize :h, Hash
```

then the model will load the text from `h`, parse the YAML to get an `ActionController::Parameters` instance, and call `to_h` on it to make sure it has a Hash, and you get an exception.

## What To Do About It

There are a couple things you need to do:

1. Fix your controllers to make sure they get real hashes out of `params`.
2. Fix your data so that you have serialized hashes rather than `ActionController::Parameters` instances.

Fixing the controllers is a simple matter of calling `to_unsafe_h` on the parameters that aren't yet real hashes.

Fixing the data is uglier. I'd probably go through the tables using the low level database interface (i.e. no ActiveRecord anywhere), read the YAML out from each row, `YAML.load` it, convert it to a hash by calling `to_unsafe_h` on it, and then writing back `the_real_hash.to_yaml` text. You could use a `like '--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters%'` filter in the WHERE clause to only deal with the broken rows.

I'd also strongly recommend that you stop using `serialize` while you're there. `serialize` is a bit of a kludge and there's no sane way to work with YAML inside the database; there's also little need for it now that both PostgreSQL and MySQL have native JSON support (but I'm not sure how well ActiveRecord supports MySQL's JSON).