# How do I read a custom serialized YAML object (written by Rails) with Python?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, yaml, pyyaml

I am working with a Rails database that contains serialized values in one column. These values *should* have been regular `Hash`es, but due to improperly sanitizing the parameters they were stored as `HashWithIndifferentAccess` or `Parameters`. For example, one column entry looks like this:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  windowHeight: 946
  documentHeight: 3679
  scrollTop: 500
permitted: false
```

I want to read this with Python's `yaml` implementation, but when I try to do so, I get:

```
*** yaml.constructor.ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag '!ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters'
  in "<unicode string>", line 1, column 5:
    --- !ruby/object:ActionController::P ...
        ^
```

So, for some reason it expects a constructor. But quite obviously, the value itself is just a regular dictionary. How can I still read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `add_constructor(loader, node)` function of the PyYAML parser, which lets you implement custom constructors for object types that it does not recognize.

In that constructor, the function `loader.construct_pairs(node)` can be called to obtain key-value tuples from the original node contents. Using a dictionary comprehension, we can create the original dictionary.

Since the entry is nested, we have to apply the constructor to both object types.

A complete example would be the following:

```
import yaml

def convert_entry(loader, node):
    return { e[0]: e[1] for e in loader.construct_pairs(node) }

yaml.add_constructor('!ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess', convert_entry)
yaml.add_constructor('!ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters', convert_entry)

yaml.load(input_string)
```

This is [somehow documented](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) but it's hard to find a lot of examples.

Comment: Any chance of getting the Rails code fixed to properly YAMLizied `params`? They probably want to say `params.to_unsafe_h.to_yaml` instead of `params.to_yaml`.

Comment: @muistooshort Yes, that's exactly what we've done now for new entries—slowly migrating the old ones to the correct format, but it takes a while.

Comment: I've come across this problem before (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50545931/479863), might make sense to switch to JSON or something along the way but that's probably out of scope.